# How to boot Windows 8 in a dual boot along with Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-8, multi-boot

I have installed a Windows 8 evaluation about a week ago. Usually, it asks me every time I turn on my computer whether to boot into Windows 8 or Windows 7. The default was Windows 8 after 30 seconds.

I changed that just yesterday to be default Windows 7 after 5 seconds. And after I changed the setting, I went ahead and went into Windows 8 and did my work.

Today, when I turned on my computer, it is failing to ask me which one to boot it in. It simply boots directly into Windows 7. Is there any reason for this? Can I no longer boot into Windows 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the System Configuration's Boot tab. It has a Timeout option, along with other options such as selecting the operating system, and seeing if both are indeed installed.